# Spring Inheritance not working

Tags: java, spring

I have The following 4 classes:
CarApplication [main class],
Honda extends Vehicle ,
Vehicle , and 
VehicleType

This is Vehicle Class:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
public class Vehicle {

    @Autowired
    public VehicleType type;
    public String getType() {
        return type.getType();
    }
}
```

This is Honda Class:

```
public class Honda extends Vehicle{

    private String motor = "honda motor";

    public void displayMotor(){
        System.out.println(motor);


        System.out.println(getType()); 
    }

}
```

This is VehicleType class:

```
public class VehicleType {

    private String type;

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }


}
```

This is main class:

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class CarApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");

        Honda honda = (Honda)ctx.getBean("honda");
        honda.displayMotor();



    }

}
```

The following is my Spring context file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">


    <bean id="honda" class = "mq.spring.practice1.Honda" parent ="vehicle"/>
    <bean id="vehicle" class = "mq.spring.practice1.Vehicle"/>
    <bean id ="type" class="mq.spring.practice1.VehicleType">
        <property name="type" value="car"/>
    </bean>






 </beans>
```

I get the following error when i run this:

```
Exception in thread "main" honda motor java.lang.NullPointerException
  at mq.spring.practice1.Vehicle.getType(Vehicle.java:11)
  at mq.spring.practice1.Honda.displayMotor(Honda.java:11)
  at mq.spring.practice1.CarApplication.main(CarApplication.java:15)
```

I debug it and found out that public VehicleType type is null. Am i doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I'm no Spring annotations expert but how is gonna be injected type in Vehicle if you do not have a setType(VehicleType type) method.

Comment: Setter method is not required if you use annotation (@Autowired). Spring container will automatically create an instance of that object as you described in your context .xml. If you dont use annotation then you have to use the setter and getter method in order to invoke injection. Remember that the variable name of that class has to be the same as bean id.

Comment: You're right. I came from an older version of Spring. Must study more, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below to context file:

```
<context:annotation-config />
```

is required to activate annotations in beans already registered in the application context